# Random not returning expected results

Tags: python-3.x

`#Python 3.7.2`So i'm new and just simply want my program to run "True" if both random numbers match and "False" if they don't and this may seem incredibly basic for everyone, but i'm slow...

```
def firstSet():
  import random
  for x in range(1):
    return(random.randint(1,10))

def secondSet():import random
  for x in range(1):
    return(random.randint(1,10))

def view():
  return(secondSet(), firstSet())

def theMatch():
  if secondSet() == firstSet():
    return(True, view())
  else:
    return(False, view())

print(theMatch()) 


theMatch()
```

I expect the output to be something like `(True, (5, 5))` or `(False, (2,3))` but the actual output is usually something like `(True, (10, 2))` or `(False, (7,7))` just completely random. I understand that there is loads of different ways to write this program in simpler ways but just want to know where I went wrong. Thanks

Comment: Your code is recalculating the random values multiple times....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

welcome to Stack Overflow.

The reason your code is not functioning correctly is because you are actually recalculating that "random" value multiple times, including *after* you check to see if they match or not, and you are recalculating it before you print.

Let's walk through your code a bit: 
When you call theMatch(), the following happens:

1. If secondset() == firstset(): Here, you are calculating the random
   values, andif they match, return true, and return ANOTHER set of
   random variables (since you are calling view(), which calls
   secondset and firstset)
2. If they dont, return "False", and then you call view again, which recalculates random integers again

An example program (with comments) to achieve what you want is below:

```
# Grab the random library
import random

# Create a function to calculate a random number
def create_random_number():
    # No need for a loop, just use x to denote a random number between 1 and 10
    x = random.randint(1,10)
    # Return that random number
    return x

# This is your main function.
# This is sometimes called a "driver" program
def main():
    # Store a random value in the first_val variable
    first_val = create_random_number()
    # Store a random value in the second_val variable
    second_val = create_random_number()

    # If they added up, print out what they were, and that it was a true match
    if first_val == second_val:
        print(first_val, " and ", second_val, " match, this is TRUE")
    # If not, print out what they were, and that it was not a match
    else:
        print(first_val, " and ", second_val, " do not match, this is FALSE")

# Actually execute your main function
main()
```

Hopefully this helps answer your question. Shortly, it is because you are comparing two values and then grabbing ***different*** random values to print out (it helps to sequentially walk through the logic of these functions, and what is happening).

Here is your code commented explaining what is happening:

```
def firstSet():
  import random
  for x in range(1):
    return(random.randint(1,10))

def secondSet():import random
  for x in range(1):
    return(random.randint(1,10))

def view():
  return(secondSet(), firstSet())

def theMatch():
    # This pair here are the first and second random integers
  if secondSet() == firstSet():
    # Now, view() gets called which returns the functions, therefore returning a DIFFERENT set of random integers than the ones being tested
    return(True, view())
  else:
    # Now, view() gets called which returns the functions, therefore returning a DIFFERENT set of random integers than the ones being tested
    return(False, view())

print(theMatch()) 


theMatch()
```

And here is a fix for your code that seemingly works for me:

```
def firstSet():
    import random
    for x in range(1):
        return(random.randint(1,10))

def secondSet():
    import random
    for x in range(1):
        return(random.randint(1,10))

def theMatch():
    firstVal = firstSet()
    secondVal = secondSet()

    if secondVal == firstVal:
    # Now, view() gets called which returns the functions, therefore returning a DIFFERENT set of random integers than the ones being tested
        return(True, secondVal, firstVal)
    else:
    # Now, view() gets called which returns the functions, therefore returning a DIFFERENT set of random integers than the ones being tested
        return(False, secondVal, firstVal)

print(theMatch()) 


theMatch()
```